# Java: passing an argument with a different type to a function

Tags: java, parameter-passing, implicit-conversion

In Java, suppose we have a function with the parameter `double a`. Does it work if I pass an integer as argument? (I mean, is there an implicit conversion?) And in the opposite case: if I have e.g. an integer as parameter, and I pass a double?

Unluckily, I am not able to compile my code at the moment, and I would like to check this assert.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Passing an int instead of a double, fine. Passing a float instead of a double, fine. Passing a double instead of either of those? No no no no.

Comment: I hoped Java would have been more "flexible" about this... :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See [JLS - Section # 5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) for details on `Method Invocation Conversion`.

> Method invocation contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> ```
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by widening reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening primitive conversion.
> ```

So, your first invocation(`int` to `double`) will work fine according to *rule # 2*.

But the second invocation(`double` to `int`) will give *Compiler Error*, according to the statement quoted further in the same section: -

> If the type of the expression cannot be converted to the type of the
>   parameter by a conversion permitted in a method invocation context,
>   then a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 3):

Because you can set a double to an integer, then integer as argument is ok to function with double as parameter. Other way round fails. In that case you need to cast the double to an int.   Same applies to normal assignents eg..

```
  int i = 6;
  double d = 0;
  d = i;  /* ok
  i = d ; /* not ok
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get sometimes get around this by making your function take a parameter of `Number`.  This is an Object which both `Integer` and `Double` inherit from, so up to the point where a `Double` number and an `Integer` number behave the same, this will work.

Note that there is a difference between the primitives `integer` and `double` and the Objects `Integer` and `Double`.  Java uses autoboxing to automatically convert between these types in function calls, etc.

Comment: Yeah this will work according to `rule # 4`. Note that after boxing, you cannot widen from `Integer` to `Double`, as it is not supertype of `Integer`, you must use `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Initially **primitive widening** will happen for a primitive type.
For example you want to call

```
 int input = 5; //int variable;
 apply(input); //calling method with int value.
```

But your class not contains a method which argument accept **int** so compiler will go for **primitive widening**. It will check any **apply** method with **java long** argument present or not. If present that method will be invoked. If not it will check for **apply** with a **float** argument is present and then it will be selected. If that also not find it will look for **apply** with a **double** argument.

```
public void apply(long input) {
    System.out.println("long");   // first pick by the compiler.
}
public void apply(float input) {
    System.out.println("float"); // if above method not found this will be selected.
}
public void apply(double input) {
    System.out.println("double"); // above two methods not present this will be selected.
}
```

Next, If all above three methods not found then compiler will look for **Autoboxing** this and try to convert that to its corresponding wrapper. for **int** its **java.lang.Integer**.So it will check for **apply** with **Integer** argument. If this found compiler will execute this method.

```
public void apply(Integer input) {
    System.out.println("Integer");
}
```

Finally if none of the above present, compiler looks for any method with name **apply** which accepts **int...**   or   **Integer...** and the method is invoked.

```
public void apply(int... input) {
    System.out.println("int...");
}
```

If your class contains only below two methods

```
public void apply(long input) {
    System.out.println("long");
}
public void apply(float input) {
    System.out.println("float");
}
```

and you want to pass a **double** value in to this method, it wont compile.

```
double input = 5d;
apply(input); 
// The method apply(long) in the type YourClass 
//is not applicable for the arguments (double
```

If you want to make that work you have to type cast that to something which can be accepted by your methods.

```
apply((int) input);
```

Then compiler will try to find a match by exact type or primitive widening or autoboxing or array matching way.