# Why does double parameterised function accepts float and not vice versa?

Tags: java

I have encountered something strange today. The below code compiles unexpectedly and runs fine.

```java
public class Test {

    public static void func(double d) {
        System.out.print("d : " + d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float f = 10.0f;
        func(f); // output: d : 10.0
    }
}
```

But this one gives compilation error

```java
public class Test {

    public static void func(float f) {
        System.out.print("f : " + f);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 10.0d;
        func(d);
    }
}
```

Can somebody please explain this behaviour ?

Comment: Does this explain it? [float and double datatype in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java/27598164)

Comment: No it does not explain this. its just compares float and double data types. But I wonder why java accepts float instead of double and not vice versa

Comment: Related: [Java: passing an argument with a different type to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277655/java-passing-an-argument-with-a-different-type-to-a-function) and [Java overloading - long and float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43796767/java-overloading-long-and-float)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type promotion from `float` to `double` is safe as no data is lost and all `float` 4 bytes can fit into `double` 8 byes.

However the opposite, from `double` to `float`, always truncates the data as  `double` 8 bytes can't fit into `float` 4 bytes. Compiler guards against doing this truncation accidentally by forcing the programmer to manually specify the type conversion.

Comment: yes thats sounds reasonable but what if we ovverload the function ? it is going to be confusing for me :D

Comment: @OğuzhanAygün see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109231/method-overload-resolution-in-java) but there are also gotchas [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54118123/why-compiler-thinks-byte-and-char-are-ambigious).

Answer (score 1):

`double`(8 byte) is a bigger data type than `float`(4 byte) so you can store `float`(4 byte) in `double`(8 byte) but you can't `double` in `float`. If you try to do that you'll get `Possible loss of precision` error.

So the following will give error.

```
float f = 120.55;
```

While this one don't

```
double d = 120.44f;
```